# Chrome, FileReader API, event.target.result === ""

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filereader

I have a web app which does some processing on big text-files (> 500mb) via the `FileReader` API's `readAsText()` method.
It has been working great for years but suddenly I got empty responses: `event.target.result` is an empty string.

369MB works but 589MB does not work.

I have tested on multiple computers; same result, however it does work in Firefox.
Chrome must have introduced this in a recent update.

Has this bug been submitted?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: You realize that the resulting string (which is stored internally using UCS-2 encoding) would be over 1GB in-memory? You'll need to develop a streaming approach in order to process this file in smaller chunks.

Comment: As I stated in question. This has worked perfectly until recently in Chrome. Works in Firefox.

Comment: Just because it has worked doesn't make it a viable approach. It's unreasonable to expect any browser not to run out of process memory when buffering a 1GB string.

Comment: Any error you are getting in `reader.onerror` property?

Comment: Where do your files come from? What encoding are you text files using? (Ps: I also faced that issue recently... Even happens for network requests with XHR )

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I did not ask if it was a viable approach. It was perfectly viable to me since it worked without any problems for years!

Comment: @PranavSingh onerror is null

Comment: @Kaiido It's text-files.

Comment: @Joe yes I understood that. I asked *"Where do your files come from?"*  -> Network?, <input>?, something else? And *"What encoding are you[r] text files using?"* -> UTF-8? ANSI? Shift-JIS? ...

Comment: @Kaiido It's ASCII. The file come from localdisk. <input type="fil"..>

Comment: You could also try `blob.text()` or `new Response(blob).text()` i don't know if it will work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This is v8 limitation on String length.

> Has this bug been submitted?

Here is the responsible commit: https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/ea56bf5513d0cbd2a35a9035c5c2996272b8b728

Running a bisect I felt on [this Change-Log](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/21ed43fb0e53464aa6d07e18db680ace0468ae2b..d84a32443b2734e65c6fe6cda3aae04bee607bad) and found it was applied on Chrome v79.

Before this change the limit on 64-bits platforms was set to 1024MB, the new limit is 512MB, the half.

This means not only FileReader is affected, but any method that would try to produce such a big String.

Here is a simple example:

```js
const header = 24;
const bytes = new Uint8Array( (512 * 1024 * 1024) - header );
let txt = new TextDecoder().decode( bytes );
console.log( txt.length ); // 536870888
txt += "f"; // RangeError
```

> Is there any workaround?

The only way around that issue is to process your text by chunks.

Luckily, you are dealing with ASCII data, so you can easily split your resource and work on that chunk using the [`Blob.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) method:

```js
// working in a Web-Worker to not freeze the tab while generating the data
const worker_script = `
(async () => {

  postMessage( 'Generating file, may take some time...' );

  const bytes = Uint8Array.from(
    { length: 800 * 1024 * 1024 },
    (_, i) => (i % 25) + 65
  );
  const blob = new Blob( [ bytes ] );

  const length = blob.size;
  const chunk_size = 128 * 1024 * 1024;

  postMessage( 'Original file size: ' + length );
  
  let As = 0;
  let i = 0;
  while ( i < length ) {
    const str = await blob.slice( i, i + chunk_size ).text();
    i += chunk_size;
    As += str.split( 'A' ).length - 1;
  }
  postMessage( 'found ' + As + ' "A"s in the whole file' );

} )();
`;
const worker_blob = new Blob( [ worker_script ] );
const worker = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL( worker_blob ) );
worker.onmessage = (evt) => console.log( evt.data );
```

The ones working with rich text like UTF-8 would have to deal with multi-bytes characters, and this may not be that easy...

Also note that even in browsers that let you generate such big strings, you may very well face other problems too. For instance in Safari, you can generate bigger strings, but if you keep it alive too long in memory, then the browser will reload your page automaticaly.

---

#### 2021 update

Almost all modern browsers now support the `Blob.stream()` method which returns a ReadableStream, allowing us to well... read that Blob's content as a stream. We can thus process huge file texts in a more performant way, and thanks to the stream option of the TextDecoder API we can even handle non ASCII characters:

```js
const bytes = Uint8Array.from(
  { length: 800 * 1024 * 1024 },
  (_, i) => (i % 25) + 65
);
const blob = new Blob( [ bytes ] );

console.log( 'Original file size: ' + blob.size );
const reader = blob.stream().getReader();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
let As = 0;
reader.read().then( function process({ done, value }) {
  const str = decoder.decode( value, { stream: true } );
  As += str.split( 'A' ).length - 1;
  if( !done ) {
    reader.read().then( process );
  }
  else {
    console.log( 'found ' + As + ' "A"s in the whole file' );
  }
} );
```

Comment: Great answer. Was that commit a fix? So the previous one allowed 2**30, the bug version 2**28 and the fix 2**29? How much is 2**29 in megabyte? Can I see somewhere when this fix will be deployed?

Comment: `2**29` is `512*1024*1024` -> 512MB, which is the current limit... There is something weird with these commits in my answer... The ChangeLog is from 7 months ago while the v8 commit is from 2 months ago. I think I caught the 1024MB -> 256MB change in the ChangeLog, and somehow missed the bump 256 -> 512... I'll run a new bisect

Answer (score 1):

Here is a alternative (modern) solution to read large files

```js
file_or_blob
  .stream()
  .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
  .pipeTo(new WritableStream({
    write(textChunk) {
      // document.body.append(textChunk)
      console.log(textChunk)
    }
  }))
```

Comment: I just found that by reading a large file in chunks this solution works perfectly. However if I store all chunks in one variable (so to say merge all of them) will it still cause a heck up? In other words this new variable will be larger than 500 MB again  @Endless

Comment: Yes it would. in the end it would be the same as doing just `var text = await blob.text()`, You could hover save it as an array of string if you wish `var body = ["hello wo", "rld"]`

Comment: thanks for the answer! So you're saying that basically I could store these chunks in the array of strings? Since I need to send this as one string eventually to the backend I could then just merge them before sending. Would it be ok? @Endless

Comment: My advise wold be to upload a blob instead. possible using FormData. if you don't need to read the file then all the better

Comment: How would we do json.parse() on the string?