# Reader Onprogress Event Does Not Work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an onProgress event to open and view a file on the first progress event. The code works on Chrome and Safari, but on Firefox I get an error that says

```
TypeError: contents is null
```

Here is what I am trying to do and what works on the other browsers:

```
reader.onprogress = function() {
    var contents = this.result
    //do stuff with progress data

},false;
reader.readAsText( file );
```

Contents is null on Firefox during this progress event. Why does this only not work on Firefox? Does Firefox not except this type of Event and if so, is there a universal Event that would work on all browsers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more with other browsers not really supporting this event correctly.

The *progess* event [should fire during the read operation](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#ref-for-dfn-progress-event), when a new Blob chunk has been read into memory but **before** the reader has finished reading the whole Blob, and thus before it has any *result* available.

> 4. If `chunkPromise` is fulfilled with an object whose `done` property is false and whose `value` property is a `Uint8Array` object, run these steps:
>    [...]
>    3 - If roughly 50ms have passed since these steps were last invoked, queue a task to fire a *progress event* called `progress` at fr.
> 5. Otherwise, if `chunkPromise` is fulfilled with an object whose `done` property is true, queue a task to run the following steps and abort this algorithm:
>    [...]
>    4 - Else:
>
>    - 1 Set fr’s `result` to `result`.

So as you can see, the FileReader's (*fr*) `result` is only set when the `done` property of `chunkPromise` is `true`, and that is **after** the progress event named `progress` is fired.

**If you want to access the reader's `result`, then listen for the `load` event, not for `progress`.**

**If you really need to read this Blob by chunks, then you'll have to build your own FileReader, using the [TextDecoder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder).**

Even if the browser did expose the internal buffered data in the progress event, this wouldn't be text yet. The [*package data*](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob-package-data) algorithm is the one responsible for actually converting the bytes data to the output format (here text). This is done only two sub-steps before the aforementioned step 10.5.4, only when *`chunkPromise` is fulfilled with an object whose `done` property is true*.
In other words, the process is to first get all the data as an ArrayBuffer, and then process that full ArrayBuffer to whatever output format was required.

Given how Unicode text encoding works, you can't even directly read as text the Blob by chunks that you would have created with `Blob.slice()`, because you could very well fall in the middle of a composed character boundary and break the whole chunk.

Fortunately for us, the TextDecoder API is able to read a stream of data, thanks to the [`stream` member of its option parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/decode#Parameters) which means that using this API, we can pass it chunks of data, and it will be able to read it without mangling characters.

So now, all we have to do is to read chunks of our Blob as ArrayBuffers (using `Blob.arrayBuffer()` is straightforward, but we could use a FileReader as fallback for older browsers), and fire the progress event at every new chunks.

```js
class StreamTextReader extends EventTarget {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.result = "";
  }
  async read( blob, chunksize = blob.size, encoding ) {
    const queueEvent = (name) => {
      const evt = new ProgressEvent( name );
      setTimeout( () => this.dispatchEvent( evt ) );
    };
    try {
      const decoder = new TextDecoder( encoding );
      this.result = "";
      let current_byte = 0;
      const last_byte = blob.size;

      while( current_byte < last_byte ) {

        const chunk = blob.slice( current_byte, current_byte + chunksize );
        const buf = await chunk.arrayBuffer();
        this.result += decoder.decode( buf, { stream: true } );

        current_byte += chunksize;
        queueEvent( 'progress' );
        
      }
      queueEvent( 'load' );
      return this.result;
     }
     catch( err ) {
      console.log(err);
      queueEvent( 'error' );
      throw err;
     }     
  }
}

const blob = new Blob( [ 'fooÀÂâà'.repeat( 10 ) ] );
const reader = new StreamTextReader();

reader.addEventListener('progress', (evt) => {
  console.log( "in progress", reader.result );
} );
reader.addEventListener('load', (evt) => {
  console.log( "in load", reader.result );
} );
reader.addEventListener('error', (evt) => {
  console.log( 'An error occured' );
} );
// read by chunks of 8 bytes
reader.read( blob, 8 );
```

And to prove FileReader's inability to handle such streaming processing, here is the result of reading the first chunk of the same Blob:

```js
const blob = new Blob( [ 'fooÀÂâà'.repeat( 10 ) ] );
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener( 'load', (evt) => console.log( reader.result ) );

reader.readAsText( blob.slice( 0, 8 ) );
```

#### Final note

Beware [javascript engines do put a max length on strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271613/chrome-filereader-api-event-target-result/61316641#61316641), in SpiderMonkey I think its about 1GB, but in V8 it's *only* 512MB, so if you are going to read very big files, it's something you need to handle, but I leave this to you as an exercise.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! I wanted to use progress because I don't want to read in the entire file because it may be very large, so I just wanted to read until the first progress event. What is the proper way to get the data from just the progress without reading in the full file?

Comment: @JSONK. I did edit my answer with such a stream reader and explanations about why FilerReader is anapt here.

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry for all of the questions but for some reason that method only works for me on Firefox and not other browsers. Tried it on Safari and got an error

Comment: And also being able to stop it after just one chunk

Comment: @JSONK., Safari doesn't support EventTarget as a constructor, you'd have to build the optional addEventListener and dispatchEvents yourself, also it doesn't support Blob.arrayBuffer, but you can polyfill it there really easily with new Response(this).arrayBuffer. This code works as is in FF and Chrome, but is just a proof of concept, the core being Blob.slice and TextDecoder.decode(buf, {stream:true}) which have wide support. The implementation is up to you, that's not the job of SO anwerers.