# Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters in JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

I have JSON file which has json data of size 914MB. I loading the file with `fs-extra` and parsing it. But when i parse it get error as

> cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters

Below is code

```
        const fs = require('fs-extra');
        const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('src/raw.json');
        const data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

I am running the project with `npm` and to run i have below command in `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
   
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=4096' ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src --env=development",
  
  }
```

Comment: Your server process doesn't have enough memory. Operating systems impose limits on resources  single process can consume. There are usually ways to instruct the OS that your process should be given more memory, but without knowing anything else about what you're doing it's impossible to provide more information.

Comment: @Pointy That error message sounds more like a hard-coded limitation in the implementation, not something coming from the OS. It's probably related to the way the length of strings is represented.

Comment: @Barmar if you google the error message, various different lengths come up. I suspect you're basically right, but it probably depends on the OS in various ways. *edit* and clearly the most important question is why you'd have a 900 megabyte JSON file.

Comment: @Pointy Maybe they use JSON to backup their database. :)

Comment: @Pointy Well i need to test my code with heavy data .that's why

Comment: I've worked with very large databases and processing a 900MB JSON file is never something I've had to do. For one thing, JSON is a *really* inefficient storage format.

Comment: @Pointy I just need to some purpose really. can you help?

Comment: [See this Node changelist.](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/ea56bf5513d0cbd2a35a9035c5c2996272b8b728). Node has a maximum string length of about 512MB, and that cannot be changed. It is part of the Node architecture.

Comment: Try using a streaming JSON parser instead.

Comment: Yes, a streaming parser would be good, though I would not be surprised if another memory limit might get involved once the code starts assembling the data structure itself. Again, knowing the application details might allow people to provide suggestions for an *architectural* change.

Comment: "It is part of the Node architecture.", it's actually a v8 on 64bits systems limit, [Chrome is also concerned.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271613/chrome-filereader-api-event-target-result). You'd need a stream-parser

Comment: @TechChain Can you provide a follow up? This question has been getting a lot of visibility, and you would help the community by sharing your solution and why it worked for you. If mine worked, you ought to mark it as `accepted`. If nothing has worked you ought to provide more details about what you tried.

Answer (score 32):

### `0x1fffffe8` is exactly 512MB.

The many commenters are correct: you are bumping up against a system limit.  I agree with @Pointy that it is mostly likely a Node string length limit. [`fs-extra` has nothing to do with the limit](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/issues/653#issuecomment-449763179)

In any case, you're going to have to process that JSON in chunks. Below are different ways to do this.

### `A:` Use a SAX-style JSON parser

You have many parser options. To get you started, here are a couple I found on NPM:

- [BFJ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj) has a `walk` function that does SAX-style parsing. BFJ is archived, but still has millions of weekly downloads.
- [stream-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json)

### `B:` Implement a [Node Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) pipeline

Almost certainly your massive JSON data is a array at the root level. This approach uses a parser that can *asynchronously* process each element in that array individually, or in batches, whichever makes sense. It is based on the very powerful and flexible [Node Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) API.

ℹ️ If your data isn't an JSON array, but a stream of concatenated JSON objects, then it probably conforms to the [JSON Streaming protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming). See option `D` below.

- [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) lets you filter by path or pattern in its streaming parse. It is archived, but still has millions of weekly downloads
- [BFJ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj) - in addition to supporting SAX-style `walk` function mentioned above, it does selective object level streaming:

  > `match` returns a readable, object-mode stream and asynchronously parses individual matching items from an input JSON stream.
- [stream-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) has a `Pick` pipeline operator that can pick desired items out of a stream, ignoring the rest. Many other options.
- [jsonparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonparse)

### `C:` Manual chunking

This will likely be the most efficient if your data supports it.

This option is like `B`, except instead of employing a streaming parser, you do the chunking yourself. This is easy to do if the elements of the JSON data array are very regular, e.g. each element occupies exactly N lines. You can easily extract them without parsing.

For example, if your data looked like this:

```
{
  data: [
    { name: ...,
      address: ... },
    { name: ...,
      address: ... },
    { name: ...,
      address: ... },
    { name: ...,
      address: ... }
  ]
}
```

Your process would be something like this:

1. Use a buffered reader to read the file.
   (DO NOT synchronously read it all into memory)
2. Discard the first two lines
3. Read the file in chunks, two lines at a time
4. If a chunk starts with `{`, remove any trailing
   comma and parse each individual
   `{name:..., address:...}` record.
5. If it doesn't, you have reached the end of the
   array. Discard the rest of the file or hand it
   off to some other process if you expect
   some other data there.

The details will depend on your data.

### `D:` Use a [JSON Streaming protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming) parser

The JSON Streaming protocol is a stream of multiple JSON objects concatenated in a stream. If that's what you have, you should use a parser that supports this protocol.

- [ndjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndjson)

Comment: I have tried most of the options but they don't work.

Comment: What do you mean they don't work? Please explain in detail. I can't help you with a comment like that.

Comment: Your case is a very common programming problem. It's not special at all. You are definiutely not doing something right. Are you STILL trying to load it into memory as ONE string? If you are, then you aren't understanding what we've all said, nor do you understand my solution for you, and you will keep getting the same error no matter what you try. You need to PROCESS it in chunks, NOT load it into a `string` using an alternate JSON parser.

Comment: Tried "most" of them? `stream-json` linked in this answer works with huge JSON files.

Comment: stream-json works. The api is confusing though

Comment: 0x1fffffe8 bytes is neither 512 MB nor 512 MiB. It’s some bytes shy of 512 MiB.

Comment: And also, it’s about the length of a `string`, which is counted in UTF-16 units, not the byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## The V8 string size limit

```
import NodeBuffer from "node:buffer";
```

> #### [`NodeBuffer.constants.MAX_STRING_LENGTH`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufferconstantsmax_string_length)
>
> Represents the largest length that a `string` primitive can have, **counted in UTF-16 code units.**
>
> This value may depend on the JS engine that is being used.

The limitation imposed on a `string` is not about the byte count.

---

Node.js uses the V8 engine. A Javascript string consists of 2-octet (`uint16_t`) code units, and in the V8 engine, the maximum number of such units in a string (`string.length`) is

- (2²⁸－16) (0x0FFFFFF0 2-octet code units / about 0.5 GiB) on a 32-bit system
- and (2²⁹－24) (0x1FFFFFE8 2-octet code units / about 1 GiB) on a 64-bit system.

#### [`node/lib/buffer.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1f193165b990190074faab34f503683148816d39/lib/buffer.js#L134-L147)

```
const constants = ObjectDefineProperties({}, {
  MAX_LENGTH: {
    __proto__: null,
    value: kMaxLength,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
  },
  MAX_STRING_LENGTH: {
    __proto__: null,
    value: kStringMaxLength,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
  },
});
```

#### [`node/src/node_buffer.cc`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1f193165b990190074faab34f503683148816d39/src/node_buffer.cc#L1302-L1306)

```
  target
      ->Set(context,
            FIXED_ONE_BYTE_STRING(isolate, "kStringMaxLength"),
            Integer::New(isolate, String::kMaxLength))
      .Check();
```

#### [`v8/include/v8-primitive.h`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1f193165b990190074faab34f503683148816d39/deps/v8/include/v8-primitive.h#L121-L127)

```
/**
 * A JavaScript string value (ECMA-262, 4.3.17).
 */
class V8_EXPORT String : public Name {
 public:
  static constexpr int kMaxLength =
      internal::kApiSystemPointerSize == 4 ? (1 << 28) - 16 : (1 << 29) - 24;
```

#### [`v8/include/v8-internal.h`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1f193165b990190074faab34f503683148816d39/deps/v8/include/v8-internal.h#L38-L41)

```
/**
 * Configuration of tagging scheme.
 */
const int kApiSystemPointerSize = sizeof(void*);
```