# Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters in React native

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a video player application and i want to play a 541mb video in react native video. when i add that 541mb mp4 video in my project , i am getting an error " Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters". How could this happen? when i remove that video file from project, there is no issue. i cant find any proper solution, i tried lots of methods from different website. Please Help me

React Native version:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
CPU: (8) x64 AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
Memory: 1.78 GB / 5.92 GB
Binaries:
Node: 15.14.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 7.7.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

[Here is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRBXp.jpg)

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s79e5.jpg)

Comment: PLease post your code as text instead of using images, [why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters in JSON.parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263704/118691) you've hit the hard limit on string size in Node of 512Mb.