# Blob is returning empty string after creation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an extremely large JSON string that I need to send to my server. I encountered `payloadTooLargeError` when I tried sending the JSON string directly.

So, I decided to send it as a blob instead. But unfortunately, after creating the blob, the blob is returning an empty string.

Here is how I created the blob:

```
 let largeContentPayload = {
        data: {
            'batch_id': batchId,
            content: extremelyLargeJSON
        }
    };
    const largeContentStringified = JSON.stringify(largeContentPayload);
    const largeContentBlob = new Blob([largeContentStringified], {
        type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    });
    console.log(largeContentBlob); //This is only returning size and type, the JSON string is not there
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(largeContentBlob);
    let requestBody = new FormData();
    let blob = await fetch(blobUrl).then(r => r.blob());
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Are you in charge of the server? You may wanna set the payload size higher to fit your needs.

Comment: Note that you may also face https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271613/chrome-filereader-api-event-target-result

Comment: @SilvanBregy Yes, I am in charge of the server. However, I do not want to explicitly set all the limit settings they suggested in my server. I would rather want to do it well coz I feel that on the occasion the limit is exceeded, the issue might come up again. So, I decided to always send it as a file.

Comment: Unrelated,  but in your code what's the purpose of the lines `const blobUrl = ...` and below? To send that data to the server you don't need the blob URI and even less to fetch it again, this only creates a copy of the Blob's data in memory. (data that is immutable btw, so there is really no point at all to do this)

Answer (score 1):

By default if you try to log a `blob` object in the console it will only display the `size` and `type` of that `blob`.

If you want to see the text content of the `blob`, you can use [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) method in the blob.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#extracting_data_from_a_blob)

**Example**

```js
async function createBlob() {
  const obj = { hello: 'world' };
  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], { type: 'application/json' });
  console.log(blob);
  const text = await (new Response(blob)).text();
  console.log(text);
}
createBlob();
```